# VBA: test for top of call stack

Tags: vba

I would like to test if a procedure is called directly by the user (so it is on top of the call stack, see ctrl+L in debug mode) or called from another procedure.

Does someone know a way to do this without tracking the call stack in a parameter passed in each procedure?

I tried to do this using a **public** parameter *topOfCallStackFound* and then adding to each procedure some code like:

```
select case topOfCallStackFound
   case false
      currentProcedureIsTopOfCallStack = true
      topOfCallStackFound = true
   case true
      currentProcedureIsTopOfCallStack = false
end select
```

But this doesn't work because VBA remembers the value of *topOfCallStackFound* after code execution is finished! The lifetime of *topOfCallStackFound* only ends when the workbook is closed, an *end* command is given or in a few other not useful circumstances. If it is possible to end the lifetime of *topOfCallStackFound* when code execution is finished and/or reinitializing *topOfCallStackFound* to false when the user starts new code execution, I would be done.

Thanks!

Comment: You may find the this useful: [Excel VBA Global error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14945634/138938).

Answer (score 1):

in VBA there is no normal way to see the callstack.
This is because the accessing this callstack via api is part of the low level compiler that is not part of the VBA.

You can view the callstack view the windows, as the VBE compiles the VBA and runs it and therefore has access to the VBA callstack but it does not expose it to the VBA.

You can however use try to use something like this:
http://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.htm

Comment: Thanks Dory. Unfortunately the link is not working. Can you post it again?