# Using Error Handling in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out if it is possible for all my subs to have a single error handler? I am in a condition where I need to exit the sub whenever there is an error and skip all of the next subs.

```
Sub Runall()
Call A
Call B
Call C 
Call D
End sub
```

Now if there is  a error in Sub A I don't want to run B,C,D and same thing for B. Where Should my I put my error handler? I am practically very confused as how does use of EXIT statement matter. Please advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940697/excel-vba-global-error-handling). Can you check the accepted answer and see if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 Sub Runall()
    Call A
    On Error GoTo Errhandler
    Call B
    On Error GoTo Errhandler
    Call C 
    On Error GoTo Errhandler
    Call D
    On Error GoTo Errhandler

 ' Exit the macro so that the error handler is not executed.
 Exit Sub
    Errhandler:
    ' If an error occurs, display a message and end the macro.
    MsgBox "An error has occurred. The macro will end."
 End sub
```

Comment: Where can I put the error handler. Sorry but I create certain new sheets that I need to delete in case of any error Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.
Include on  `On Error GoTo Handler:` in calling sub.

Once these subs raise an error `On Error` in `RunAll` [will take over](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_23176855.html)(becuase if a sub is missing Error handler it will try to use Error Handler of calling sub) and with its `GoTo` is will skip everything untill it sees `Handler`.

Remeber that before `Handler` you need to incluse `Exit Sub` or VBA in `Handler` will be used regardless of if you have an error or not.

Here is a "failling" example:

```
Sub RunAll()
    On Error GoTo Handler
    Call A
    Call B
    Exit Sub
Handler:
        Debug.Print "testing"
End Sub
```

A

```
Sub A()
    Dim fail As Integer

    fail = 1 / 1
End Sub
```

B

```
Sub B()
    Dim fail As Integer

    fail = 1 / 0
End Sub
```